# ADF popup cancel listener not invoked on closing dialog with error values

Tags: jsf, richfaces, oracle-adf

The issue is when I enter some negative value in the inputBox within the dialog component and the validator throws error something like "Negative numbers not allowed". The dialog now has an error input box marked with red border and I decide to click outside the dialog to close it and reset the input box, but the inputBox is not reset and if I press Esc key or Ok button then only the popupCanceledListener is called and the inputBox is reset. Below is the code which contains a popup with dialog and inputBox within it.

JSF code:

```
<af:popup contentDelivery="lazyUncached" autoCancel="enabled"
          popupCanceledListener="#{pageFlowScope.testBean.handleResetPopup}"
          childCreation="deferred" id="testPopup">
   <af:dialog type="none" modal="false"
     id="Dlg1">
     <af:inputText label="DECIMAL PLACES"
                    columns="2"
                    validator="#{pageFlowScope.testBean.validateDecimalPlaceValue}"
                    value="#{pageFlowScope.testBean.decimalPlace}"
                    id="input1" autoSubmit="true"></af:inputText>
    <f:facet name="acceptNFChange">
      <af:commandButton text="OK" id="cb1"
                        actionListener="#{pageFlowScope.testBean.handleOkFromPopup}"
                        partialSubmit="true"></af:commandButton>
    </f:facet>
  </af:dialog>
</af:popup>
```

Bean code:

```
    public void handleResetPopup(PopupCanceledEvent popupCanceledEvent) {
    try {
        UIComponent component = popupCanceledEvent.getComponent();
        RichInputText inputText = (RichInputText)JSFUtil.findComponent(component, "input1");
        inputText.resetValue();
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        this.handleException(th);
    }
}
```

Problem: When clicking outside the dialog to close it and reset the inputbox, the popupCanceledListener is not invoked.

Comment: You might investigate if the auto cancel property is affecting this.

Comment: Changed autoCancel property to disabled and it seems it is not affecting it.

Comment: Your bean method name does not match your JSF method call.

Comment: @32U.. it was a spelling mistake.

Comment: Another approach: Instead of using validator, in the setter in backing bean for the decimalPlace, do your validation there. If issue, throw up your own popup or show error text in current popup, and clear the inputText as you do in handleResetPopup method.

Comment: @32U I would stick with the validator method based on my requirement. If I had not that requirement, I would have done it at first place as you said.

Comment: This might get you there: http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/17432.page#sthash.GSyYXQsA.dpbs

Comment: @32U Thanks for the link it was helpful for the information provided in the post. But, does not fit for the scenario I am facing right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided in this link **https://community.oracle.com/thread/4112016** works fine for my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use client listener with type popupClosed. Here is example for your code:

```
<af:popup contentDelivery="lazyUncached" autoCancel="enabled"
          popupCanceledListener="#{pageFlowScope.testBean.handleResetPopup}"
          childCreation="deferred" id="testPopup">
   <af:dialog type="none" modal="false"
     id="Dlg1">
     <af:inputText label="DECIMAL PLACES"
                    columns="2"
                    validator="#{pageFlowScope.testBean.validateDecimalPlaceValue}"
                    value="#{pageFlowScope.testBean.decimalPlace}"
                    id="input1" autoSubmit="true"></af:inputText>
    <f:facet name="acceptNFChange">
      <af:commandButton text="OK" id="cb1"
                        actionListener="#{pageFlowScope.testBean.handleOkFromPopup}"
                        partialSubmit="true"></af:commandButton>
    </f:facet>
  </af:dialog>
  <af:clientListener type="popupClosed" method="popupCloseClientListener"/> 
  <af:serverListener type="popupClosedEvent" method="#{pageFlowScope.testBean.handlePopupClosed}"/>
</af:popup>
```

then you need to write somewhere in JSF script:

```
<script>
    function popupCloseClientListener(event) {
       component = event.getSource();
       AdfCustomEvent.queue(component,
                            "popupClosedEvent",
                            {payload:component.getSubmittedValue()},
                            true);
       event.cancel();
 }
 </script> ]]>
```

In this way you can always correctly handle popup closed event from client. And implement all server logic you need.

Comment: did you try clicking outside the dialog to close it and see if the method handlePopupClosed was getting called or not?

Comment: ,, I have updated the question with more details. Have a look at it and try the same code you have posted. It does not work for me the code which you have provided.